# Сделать возможность выбора не более одного пункта

Tags: javascript, jquery

http://jsfiddle.net/0n04s1Ls/1/

HTML:

```
<input type="radio" name='abc1' class="rad" />
<input type="radio" name='abc2' class="rad" />
<input type="radio" name='abc3' class="rad" />
```

JS:

```
$('.rad').mousedown(function () {
    $(this).data('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
}).click(function () {
    var checked = $(this).data('checked');
    $('.rad').prop('checked', false);
    $(this).prop('checked', !checked);
});
```

Задача: не давать выбрать более одного инпута. Давать возможность снять выделение.
Такое впечатление, что это говнокод. Но как его значительно улучшить не знаю.

Мои варианты:
1) Все-таки назвать их одним именем - пропадет необходимость всем проставлять false;
2) использовать checkbox - пропадет необходимость проверять статус инпута, но придется всем проставлять false;

Есть ли человеческое решение?

Comment: @knes, а разве дать одно имя всем трём полям - это не выход?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/0n04s1Ls/2/ - неа. Пропала всего одна строчка. 
А хотелось бы минимум избавиться от одного события. Это можно, используя чекбокс.

Comment: @knes, я вот [об этом][1] говорил

   [1]:http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/0n04s1Ls/3/

Comment: В конце концов, если уж нужны разные имена, то [можно и так][1]:

    var rad = $('.rad');
    rad.on('change', function(){
        rad.not(this).prop('checked', false);
    });

   [1]:http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/0n04s1Ls/5/

Comment: В хроме и фф нельзя снять выделение

Comment: @knes, не очень понял про снятие выделения. Вам нужно, кроме всего прочего, дать возможность убрать выбор со всех?

Comment: Да, именно так. Причем не какой-то левой кнопкой, а повторным кликом по выделенной.

Comment: Попробуйте дать вопросу название которое бы отражало суть проблемы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[[@knes](/users/2825/knes)](/users/2825/knes), задача неординарная, поэтому я бы не сказал, что у вас какой-то *овнокод. Может быть [записать по другому](http://jsfiddle.net/Deonis/0n04s1Ls/6/), но смысл не меняется. Ну и всё-таки полям дать одно имя:

```
var stat = false;
$('.rad').on({
    mousedown: function(){
        stat = $(this).prop('checked');
    },
    click: function(e){
        if(stat) $(this).prop('checked', false);
    }
});
```